# Bind jQuery events to DIV with specific HTML TAG like TEXTAREA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have one `DIV` element which contains dynamically created `TEXTAREAs` and `<input type="file"/>` and `<input type="checkbox"/>`.

Currently I have bound three events on above `DIV` like below

```
jQuery("#uniqueId ").bind("click change keypress", function(e){
    ....
    ....
});
```

Now problems occur are when I click on `file` input button to Browse and Upload a file or check on Checkbox I receives following error

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. 

myxFunction myXjavscript.js:1172
(anonymous function) myXjavscript.js:109
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
h.handle.i
```

and because of it `file` and `checkbox` inputs are not working and throwing errors. I just want to bind above events only on `TEXTAREA` and not other elements under a `DIV`.

Reason to use `"click change keypress"` events together because in Chrome I am performing Dynamic operations on Textarea to get cursor position after add/edit/delete texts from Textarea. So to record all those things I needed to add those three events.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to bind the events to the textareas contained within #uniqueId, use the second argument (delegate selector):

```
jQuery("#uniqueId ").on("click change keypress", "textarea", function(e){
    ....
    ....
});
```

Edit: didn't realize you were using .bind, always use .on! It's awesome. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I appreciating your answer but After implementing your solution, error is gone away but still Browse button does not works at any cost :(

Comment: If I stop including jquery-1.7.1.min.js file then problem goes away ! Then other problems starts which depend on jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the element before using it like,

```
if(jQuery("textarea#uniqueId").length)
{
  jQuery("textarea#uniqueId").bind("click change keypress", function(e){
      ....
      ....
  });
}
```

**Or** if the element is exists in page then write your code in document ready function like,

```
$(function(){
  jQuery("textarea#uniqueId").bind("click change keypress", function(e){
      ....
      ....
  });
});
```

Also **id must be unique** if you `id` `conflicts` with other `elements` the you should specify `element` with id like **textarea#uniqueid**

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but code is already being called when document is ready.